# PostgresQL Error: relation <table> doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I'm new to Postgres and plpsql, so sorry if the answer is obvious. However I wasn't able to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. When I use the sample  DB function, everything is fine. When I try to create my own:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_trans (p_param VARCHAR) 
  RETURNS TABLE (
    amount money,
    transactionId UUID
  ) 
  AS $$
  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY SELECT
      amount,
      transactionId
    FROM
    transactions;
  END; $$ 

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The function executes, but testing it by running the following test statement fails:

```
SELECT * 
FROM public.get_trans(
  'bs'
)
```

with this error:

```
ERROR:  relation "public.transactions" does not exist
LINE 4:  FROM public.transactions
          ^
QUERY:  SELECT
          amount,
          transactionId
FROM public.transactions
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_trans(character varying) line 4 at RETURN 
QUERY
SQL state: 42P01
```

It looks like it's a pretty common error with plpsql, and I realize that I'm probably missing smth obvious, but none of the answers so far helped in my case.  is a straight forward stand-along table with only primary key for now.

Any tips are highly appreciated.

UPDATE: So, thanks to LD I found out that my table although created doesn't exist in any schema due to syntax errors. It turned out postgres is more different from  MSSQL as I thought, and harder to flash out script errors. The main error was - you can't use camel-case in table or column definition. Once I fixed those and rerun the function, everything as fine.

Comment: The table is probably in a different schema. Either set your `search_path` or add the schema to the table name in the function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function itself seems be ok.
Please ma sure the table transactions exists in public schema by using(check the column table_schema in results):

```
SELECT * 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE  table_name = 'transactions'
```